# Sum in Sum C# Linq MVC 5

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, asp.net-mvc-5, sum

I Have write som code that now is where slow when i have many records in my DB. Any know how to optimize this?

I have this models:

```
public class StockBalance
{
    public double stockBalanceValue()
    {
        return stockBalanceProductItems.Where(x => x.productItemStatus == ProductStatus.InStock).Select(p => p.productItemPurchaes.purchaesPrice).Sum();
    }

    public double stockBalanceCount()
    {
        return stockBalanceProductItems.Where(x => x.productItemStatus == ProductStatus.InStock).Count();

    }
}

public class Product
{
    public double productQty()
    {
        return productStockBalance.Select(x => x.stockBalanceCount()).Sum();
    }
}
```

And when i in my View want to do this its takes maybee 5 minutes to load the page the i have 4000 records in productItems Table. My tables is: Products, Stocks, StockBalance, ProductItems.

View:

```
@Stock.stockStockBalance.Select(x => x.stockBalanceValue()).Sum()
@Stocks.Sum(x => x.stockStockBalance.Sum(m => m.stockBalanceValue()))
@Product.productQty()
```

Comment: Why are you computing the sum inside your model? What's stockbalanceProductItems? what is your view's model Type? What do you controller do? there is lot of missing information please add more details to let us help

Comment: `Stocks.Sum(x => x.stockStockBalance.Sum(m => m.stockBalanceValue()))` can be replaced with `Stocks.SelectMany(x => x.stockStockBalance).Sum(m => m.stockBalanceValue)`

Comment: and it would also help to have an index on `productItemStatus`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're doing your aggregations in your view models. Perhaps you might consider moving that logic closer to your data access layer; this way you can let SQL (via Entity Framework) do the number crunching for you.